# Last successful/fail login time AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito, and would like to find out the last/previous successful login time of user for mobile app.

As per my understanding, there is no built-in support from AWS cognito, hence I am coming with two triggers `Pre authentication` and `Post authentication`, which are lambda functions to store timing into dynamodb. However, I want to ask if there is anyway to send stored timing to mobile app.

Comment: I have a similar case. Currently I am not tracking the user login in the application. Can I know how many are the active users of the website using Amazon Cognito?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not entirely sure but I think you're looking trying to [[Use] Amazon Pinpoint Analytics with Amazon Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html). With this native integration Amazon Cognito User Pools will emit events to Amazon Pinpoint Analytics.

These events will include attributes like the Cognito User Id, the event type/status (Login/Fail) as well as the timestamp. This Analytics data can then be [visualized in the Amazon Pinpoint console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/analytics.html) or [streamed to a destination of your choosing (like Amazon Redshift) for post processing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/streaming-events-from-amazon-pinpoint-to-redshift/).

Comment: Thanks for your input, its looking interesting. However, I am looking for the approach in which we can return the timing to client upon authenticated.

Comment: Hmmm I guess I'm not understanding the use case, you want the client to know when the client has logged in to cognito? Doesn't the client know by virtue of the fact that it has just logged in? I'm a little confused.

Comment: yeah, I want to have previous successful/failed login, not current one. This will help to raise fraud awareness.

Comment: You may want to look into Amazon Pinpoint endpoint profiles, you can track metrics per endpoint or per user like last login timestamp.  Otherwise you'll need to try using AppSync/DDB/Other state manager to manage your own endpoints.

Comment: Note that cognito does not communicate with pinpoint, it's the client SDK that needs to be configured to send analytics to pinpoint :(